# how to write WPF application running on system tray only?

Tags: wpf, startup, system-tray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF Application that only has a tray icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon)

how to write WPF application running on system tray only since the application start?

Comment: I was about to post an answer but was simply overcome by a deep sorrow that people keep posting questions that can be answered _fully_ with a simple search either on google or on this very site.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the App.xaml-file and implement a Main-method yourself without any window.Show() etc. You will need to use WinForm-references for the notifyicon.