# How to create WPF System Tray Icon when no "Main" host window exists

Tags: wpf, system-tray

**Background**

We have an application that sits in the background and utilizes `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor a folder for new files, when a new file appears it spawns a window.

What I need to do is create a system tray icon for this application so that we can add simple context menu items to it (being able to close the app without going into task manager is the biggest one).

**Question**

All of the search results for how to implement a system tray icon point to examples of how to add it to a WPF window not the application itself, since my app doesn't have a main window and spawns windows when an event occurs how can I implement this?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Application that only has a tray icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the application `ShutdownMode` to `OnExplicitShutdown` and display the tray icon from the `Application.OnStartup`.  This example uses the `NotifyIcon` from `WinForms`, so add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and `System.Drawing.dll`.  Also, add an embedded resource for the Tray Icon.

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTrayIcon.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
             >
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;

using NotifyIcon = System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon;

namespace WpfTrayIcon
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static NotifyIcon icon;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            App.icon = new NotifyIcon();
            icon.Click += new EventHandler(icon_Click);
            icon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(typeof(App), "TrayIcon.ico");
            icon.Visible = true;

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }

        private void icon_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Thanks for clicking me");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the icon is added via Resources in project properties, there is this small difference: `icon.Icon = MyApp.Properties.Resources.TrayIcon;`