# WPF C# Desktop Application Notification Tray Live Icon

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, notifications

I am trying to create a live notification icon for my desktop application on Windows in WPF, XAML , C#.

The icon should show on the notification tray and indicate how much battery is left for the person (attached image).

This is similar to the battery notification icons (3 hours left) and WIFI connectivity live icons one usually sees in the notification tray.

How do I create a live icon, which changes as the user's "battery" depletes.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v3At.png)

Comment: Could you include any code which shows what you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Application that only has a tray icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon)

Answer (score 0):

Use [NotifyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) from Windows Forms library.