# How to make a tasktray application work on the tasktray

Tags: c#

I want to make a task tray application to control the a micro controller  and i have made the application but i want it to be directly accessible from the task tray itself instead of the application opening.

Like this 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Application that only has a tray icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public partial class Window1 : System.Windows.Window
{

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon ni = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
        ni.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("Main.ico");
        ni.Visible = true;
        ni.DoubleClick += 
            delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                this.Show();
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            };
    }

    protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            this.Hide();

        base.OnStateChanged(e);
    }
```

More info here: [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/21992d0b-a02c-4042-a188-47b0a2b99b0b/wpf-system-tray-application?forum=wpf)