# how to hide kestrel console?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, kestrel

I have a .net core app that I want to run in background, but I can't seem to get rid of the console window of Kestrel. Is there any way to hide it without running the app as a windows service? I've tried to remove any reference related to Logger, it didnt help.
here is my Program.Main:

```
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
                .Build();
            var hostingUrl = config.GetValue<string>("HostingUrl");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostingUrl))
            {
                var xmlString = File.ReadAllText(Consts.WebHostBaseFolder + "\\web.config");
                var confDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
                hostingUrl = confDoc.Element("configuration").Element("appSettings")?.Elements("add")?.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("key").Value == "HostingUrl")?.Attribute("value")?.Value ?? "";

            }
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                            .UseKestrel()
                            .UseContentRoot(Consts.WebHostBaseFolder)
                            .UseStartup<Startup>()
                            .UseUrls(hostingUrl)
                            .Build();

                host.Run();
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that not just debugging?

Comment: nope. I added the Program.Main code, and it shows the console also when I build in release mode, and running the .exe file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the solution was using editbin.exe as described here https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/wiki/Hide-console-window-for-self-contained-.NET-Core-application

```
editbin.exe /subsystem:windows yourapp.exe
```

Comment: Or just [host an aspnet core app in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/windows-service)

Comment: Windows service is an entirely different use case with a lot of constraints and headaches of it's own. No reason to go there when all I need is a simple windows app

Comment: @YuvalPerelman Could you explain this a bit more?

Comment: Windows service runs from a different security context than the current user. It is a headache to install and uninstall. It has no access to anything that has GUI and it can't open other processes with GUI. It usually runs under admin context, so it has no access to mapped drives or stored credentials for network locations, and many other UAC related headaches. You cant have 2 instances of it running in parallel for different logged on users. It doesn't shut down when the user logs out. That's only from the top of my mind. A service and a local process are not for the same use cases.

Comment: The solution now seems to be far simpler with .net core 3.0+:

> Simply set <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType> in csproj

Comment: @YuvalPerelman thanks , this is what I needed . one more thing , any idea how I can stop this application , after hiding its cmd ,using any UI element or button or any windows icon. currently I have to stop the application from task manager.

Comment: when I had to do that I wrapped the .net core app with a win forms application that started the .net core app on start and killed it on shut down. I've added to that app a notify icon with all the functionality I needed. Here is an example as to how to add the notify icon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon