# WPF: Display notification box when my application is minimized

Tags: c#, wpf

**How to implement, using WPF, notifications mechanism similar to what eg. Chrome has?** 
By which I mean: custom content pop-up, displaying especially when my main application window is minimized.

Things I have tried out so far:

1. WPF Popup class with `StaysOpen` property set to `true`. Seems okay, except that it disappears when I minimize the main window.
2. Custom template window: well, it's a window, so it appears as another application window in the taskbar, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: this might work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon

Comment: In case of your 2nd thing, you technically can hide the new custom template window from taskbar by setting your Window's `ShowInTaskbar="False"`