# Windows application anchored in the taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, windows, anchor, taskbar

How do I create an windows application (preferably in C#) that gets anchored in the taskbar next to the system tray (similar to the Lenovo notebook battery application)?

I'm trying to display my glucose in real time on the taskbar - I need to display 3 digits (glucose) and an icon indicating if it is steady, going up or down.

Comment: Possible duplicate with this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon

Comment: Not a dup I think, The Lenovo tool isn't a Notification icon, it sits on the taskbar outside of the notification area.

Comment: Although I'm pretty sure its considered depreciated the platform API that lets you do this involves using COM to create a *DeskBand* which is effectively a reserved part of the taskbar that you can do with as you see fit. A quick Google yields https://github.com/dsafa/CSDeskBand

Comment: Alternatively you could position a transparent window wherever you like although there would be no automatic positioning.