# How can I run a WPF app In the background?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to make an app that runs in the background in WPF and need it to have a Tray Icon... I tried many different things and also found another thread with the same question, but none of those answers work...I also tried using the TrayIcon class in `System.Windows.Forms` but even after referring it through COM it still shows the error

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I also tried referencing the DLL file but when I do so all the WPF functions throw the error

> {FunctionName e.g InitializeComponent} does not exist in the current context
> Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Rather mixing your WPF with Windows.Forms you can just get a WPF dedicated lib for Trayicons. I once used https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardcodet.NotifyIcon.Wpf/ and it worked quiet good

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1472633/366064

Comment: I've used http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon in the past

Comment: @Jodn Thanks for the quick response but it throws an error that it can't find the .ico file. I tried complete path and the local path but still doesn't work...Everything else works...

Comment: Edit - Thanks a lot to everyone, it now works after restarting VS...

Comment: @Garvit13 right, that's a common bug with VS2019 currently. independent from your problem