# WPF C# Tray Icon Implementation Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, trayicon, tray

I've faced the issue while trying to implement a tray icon. App was instantly closing every time I launched it. So first thing first I decided to create a new project to try it there, just in case if I messed something up in my app.  But it proceeded to close.
In this new project, I just removed StartupUri and added this piece of code. One more important thing - If we comment the line with Drawing.Icon the window doesn't close after running despite any tray options.

```
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow = new MainWindow();
            MainWindow.Show();

            Forms.NotifyIcon _notifyIcon = new Forms.NotifyIcon();
            _notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon("icon.ico");
            _notifyIcon.Visible = true;

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
```

I would be extremely grateful if you could help me to figure it out

Comment: If you are using WPF, then why are you trying to import WinForms? Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon).

Comment: Thank you so much, Andy, you just made my evening. Thanks to you I will go to bed in a good mood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple. I was trying to import WinForms for WPF.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472633/wpf-application-that-only-has-a-tray-icon) is everything explained about Notifyicon in WPF.
Thanks to Andy